# Get Distinct record in table using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

[image: Table]

This is my table. I want to get the distinct records as unique Name , SourceDeviceId, SourceState, Id . Since ID column consists of unique numbers I am getting all the records. But I want to get any of Id with Same Name, SourceDeviceId, SourceState. I have tried to use GroupBy but I am not able to select specific columns after select statement.

Comment: So you just want a distinct list of `Name` and `SourceDeviceId` from your table?

Comment: Try to edit your question and add you code and table description into your question. Do not use images.

Comment: you can get the `Name` and `SourceDeviceId` in `select` after group by as `z.Key.Name` and `z.Key.SourceDeviceId`.

Comment: `I want to get the distinct records as unique Name , SourceDeviceId, SourceState, Id .` Every item shown in the screenshot table is distinct from all the others based on those columns. I think you need to re-explain what it is exactly that you want. Show us what you expect to get from the screenshot example. What does your intended output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a few ways, however this might help

```
var result = db.SomeTable.GroupBy(x => new
                  {
                     x.Name,
                     x.SourceDeviceId
                  })
               .Select(x => x.First())
               .ToList();
```

It gives you back a list of distinct entities by `Name` and `SerouceDeviceId`

Or if you want an anonymouse type

```
var result = db.SomeTable.GroupBy(x => new
                    {
                       x.Name,
                       x.SourceDeviceId
                    })
             .Select(x => x.Key)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: For the second example, can that not be shortened to `Select(x => x.Key)`?

Comment: My comment doesn't relate to what the OP wants. It's suggesting a refactoring of your posted code. In which case is your second solution meaningfully different from `Select(x => x.Key)`?

Comment: @Flater yeah good point, and agree after looking at it again, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Distinct`:

```
var result = db.SomeTable.Select(x => new
                {
                   x.Name,
                   x.SourceDeviceId
                })
         .Distinct()
         .ToList();
```

*The `ToList` is optional - whether you need it depends on how you plan to use `result`.*